# @Specializes - WELD-000047 Specializing bean must extend another bean: Managed Bean

Tags: java, cdi, jboss-arquillian

I have some problems with `@Specializes` annotation. In my project (Arquillian tests on JBOSS) I am using `@Alternative` annotation to create stub for interface. For this time I have to create stub which replaces Bean class I used Specializes annotation. 
When I run this test I got error:

> Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-000047 >Specializing bean must extend another bean:  Managed Bean [class com.ericsson.oss.services.security.genericidentitymgmtservice.stubs.CreateAd>ministratorStub] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]"}}

I find that people have similar problem [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/camunda-bpm-users/x8y51atX6YI)

I tried to change Weld version in pom into `1.1.11` or `2.0.0` but it won't help.
Can you suggest what I can do with this issue? Here is code sample:

ORGINAL BEAN:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class CreateAdministratorUserBean {

@Inject
private Logger log;

@Inject
private UserManager userManager;

 @PostConstruct
public void createAdministratorUser() throws IOException, InterruptedException {<code>}

private void assignAdministratorRole(User user, String roleName) {<code>}}
```

BEAN STUB:

```
@Stateless
@Startup
@Alternative
@Specializes

 public class CreateAdministratorStub extends CreateAdministratorUserBean {

 @Inject
 private Logger log;

 @Inject
 private UserManager userManager;

 @PostConstruct
 public void createAdministratorUser() throws IOException, InterruptedException {<code>}

 @Override
 private void assignAdministratorRole(User user, String roleName) {<another code>}}
```

I also added my Stub into Deployment provider class and into `beans-ejb.xml` as alternatives

Comment: You should make sure that you base-bean CreateAdministratorUserBean is correctly registered at weld bootstrap (look into the log, open it at debug level if needed). Also I noticed that your specialized Bean is a Stateless bean whereas your first bean is a Singleton EJB. Weld might be confused here!

Comment: I check both: Stateless and Singleton with the same effects. How can I use/see weld bootstrap?

Comment: set the `org.jboss.weld` log category in conf `standalone.xml` to `DEBUG` level and restart your app. You might see useful information about what WELD is doing with your CreateAdministratorUserBean.

Comment: @MichałWoźniczko I'm having a similar issue. Did you find a solution for this?